# Java GUI JTable 'refreshing'

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm making a GUI and it includes a JPanel, inside that JPanel there's a JTable, and what I want to do is: when I click a button, both of them appear (since I'm using CardLayout). Code:

```
 private void teGjithaButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
try {
    parentPanel.setVisible(true);
    parentPanel.removeAll();
    parentPanel.add(tgjPanel);
    parentPanel.repaint();
    parentPanel.revalidate();
    listAllCurtains();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainBrillant.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

And the code for listAllCurtains():

```
public void listAllCurtains() throws SQLException {
    DefaultTableModel deftm = (DefaultTableModel) allTable.getModel();

    if (deftm.getRowCount() != 0) {
        deftm.setRowCount(0);
    }

    stm = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from customerregister.curtain inner join curtainrel on curtain.code = curtainrel.curtainCode;");
    while (rs.next()) {
        String shifra = rs.getString("code");
        String ngjyra = rs.getString("color");
        String emri = rs.getString("name");
        double cmimi = rs.getDouble("price");
        double sasia = rs.getDouble("amount");
        allCurtains.add(new Curtain(shifra, ngjyra, emri, cmimi, sasia));
    }

    Object[] row = new Object[5];


    for (int i = 0; i < allCurtains.size(); i++) {
        row[0] = allCurtains.get(i).getShifra();
        row[1] = allCurtains.get(i).getEmri();
        row[2] = allCurtains.get(i).getNgjyra();
        row[3] = allCurtains.get(i).getCmimi();
        row[4] = allCurtains.get(i).getSasia();
        deftm.addRow(row);
    }

}
```

The problem is that when i re-click the button, eventhough there's this part of the code to ensure the data is not duplicated:

```
if (deftm.getRowCount() != 0) {
    deftm.setRowCount(0);
}
```

It still continues to insert the same data into table each time the button is clicked. I can't figure out why this is happening, and I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Quit reposting the same question. You were asked to post a "runnable example" in your last question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely due to this variable: `allCurtains`. You're not clearing it first, and continue to add to it, and so all old data is still held by it.

At the start of your method, clear out this collection, perhaps via `allCurtains.clear();`.

```
public void listAllCurtains() throws SQLException {
    DefaultTableModel deftm = (DefaultTableModel) allTable.getModel();

    if (deftm.getRowCount() != 0) {
        deftm.setRowCount(0);
    }
    allCurtains.clear(); // ***** add this *****

    // ..... more code
```

Other issues: you state that you're using a CardLayout, but that's not how CardLayout is used.

Comment: I'm not even going to check because you're totally right... Thank you so much.

Comment: @AskingAsker: thank you for accepting this, but camickr is right -- you should have improved the original question and supplied a viable [mcve] there. Otherwise you're not really being fair to those who put in effort to help you previously. In fact you appear to have totally ignored the answer provided there, as you've neither up-voted it (I did), accepted it, or commented to it. Please at least rectify this in fairness to DevilsHnd and his efforts.

Comment: I just started working with GUI, no experience at all, so I'm just trying to realize how stuff works. So what's the problem?

Comment: @AskingAsker: What is unclear about my comment above?

Comment: I was talking about "Other issues: you state that you're using a CardLayout, but that's not how CardLayout is used." part.

Comment: Swapping components using a CardLayout helps you avoid all that swapping code that you have posted in your code above. Google the CardLayout tutorial, as it is very well explained there. Also check out my code in some of my answers that can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a522444%20cardlayout%20swapping).